# Snowflake - While Loop using Current_Date

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In Snowflake I'm attempting to run a while loop where there is a start date, and the code will loop until it equals today's date.

I'm fairly new to snowflake itself.

First idea was in the while loop check if the variable date was less than the current date. I couldn't seem to get this working even with the Current_Date on it's own or attributed to a variable

```
 execute immediate $$
    declare
      opdate := '2022-04-29';
      currdate := Current_Date;
     begin
       while (opdate <=currdate) do
        opdate :=dateadd(day,1,opdate);
      end while;
    end;
    $$
    ;
```

> 'CURRDATE' cannot have its type inferred from initializer

The second option was to use a datediff to see if the difference between the variable and current_date was equal to zero

```
execute immediate $$
    declare
      opdate := '2022-04-29';
        currndate := 1;
     begin
       while (currndate<=0) do  
        currndate := datediff(day, opdate, CURRENT_DATE);
        opdate :=dateadd(day,1,opdate);
      end while;
    end;
    $$
    ;
```

> error line 7 at position 39 invalid identifier 'CURRENT_DATE'

I've tried many different variants of this code, even use for each and if loops with no luck. I'm seemingly unable to check if a variable is less than the current date. Any help/pointers would be much appreciated.

Without having Current_Date, and having a set start and end date, it appears to run fine

```
execute immediate $$
declare
  opdate := '2022-04-29';
  currdate := '2022-05-03';
 begin
   while (opdate <=currdate) do
    opdate :=dateadd(day,1,opdate);
  end while;
end;
$$
;
```

Comment: Regarding that first error, try `opdate := DATE '2022-04-29';` so that it doesn't have to "infer" what that string literal is. By placing `DATE` in front of it you are saying "This literal is specifically a date literal".

Comment: JNevil
Unfortunately, even specify the type as DATE still ends up with the same error.
I have played about with defining the types with no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try CURRENT_DATE() with the open and close parens? see block below

```
 execute immediate $$
    declare
      opdate := '2022-04-29';
      currdate := Current_Date();
     begin
       while (opdate <=currdate) do
        opdate :=dateadd(day,1,opdate);
      end while;
     return opdate; --added this return
    end;
    $$
    ;
```

Comment: Thank you!
That works perfectly. I had been adding Current_Date and Current_Date() with no luck but not when creating a variable from the Current_Date